# Which of these particle physics processes occurs at a higher rate?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, quarks

As in the title! The processes are:

$$cud \to sud + u\bar d$$

$$cud \to udd + \bar su$$

Obviously in the first one, the $c$ quark decays into an $s$ quark, and in the second, the $c$ quark decays into a d quark, so I'm guessing flavour mixing comes into the answer. My thinking would be that it's more likely to "keep" its flavour, and so the first option happens more often, but I'm not sure of the reasoning behind that.

Comment: Can you write down the corresponding tree W-exchange diagrams?  Is the upper one proportional to the square of the cosine of the Cabbie angle? The lower one proportional to the square of the sine?

Comment: Look at the relevant CKM matrix elements for the tree-level diagram. $V_{cs}$ and $V_{ud}$ on the diagonal, whereas $V_{cd}$ and $V_{us}$ are off-diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

The s quark is characterized by strangeness = -1 and the anti_s quark +1

> [The terms strange and strangeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness) predate the discovery of the quark, and were adopted after its discovery in order to preserve the continuity of the phrase; strangeness of anti-particles being referred to as +1, and particles as −1 as per the original definition. For all the quark flavour quantum numbers (strangeness, charm, topness and bottomness) the convention is that the flavour charge and the electric charge of a quark have the same sign.

[Here is a table](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html) of the possible quark decays:

[image]

The equivalent antiquark table has a bar over the decayed quark of the table above and appropriate charge changes for the W and further reactions.
When antiparticles decay, they decay to antiparticles, baryon  and antibaryon number is a conserved number and an antiquark has to have a -1/3  baryon number.

[Here are the quantum numbers](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html) of quarks

[image: quantumnum]

> c quark decays into a d quark,

This is not an allowed decay,

A charmed quark can only decay to an s quark, not an anti-s, or any other quark than s. The second line is also  violating flavor number conservation: anti-s flavor suddenly appears.

Comment: Be very cautious in saying that $c\to d$ is forbidden; this will generate confusion. [The quark-mixing matrix(PDF)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-ckm-matrix.pdf) indeed has a $|V_{cd}|$ element, so it happens, presumably by emission of a $W^+.$  It's just much less common than the former; the amplitudes given are 0.230 vs 1.023, and I think these need to be squared to be interpreted as actual relative frequencies meaning that the one is ~19.8 times more frequent than the other, but it's not zero because of some conservation law.

Comment: @CRDrost you may be right in this, I had been thinking  a bit of strong interaction loops but did not pursue it further because of the  anti-s,  the one in the second line.